# openprinter with winspool.drv not working

Tags: powershell, printing

As a part of my project I am learning how to handle the printers using "winspool.drv" and  "PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry" to which I am new. I am using powershell for this project. The problem is that my code is throwing an error when I am trying to get printer Handle with openprinter method
Error: Method invocation failed because [OpenPrinter1.Program1] does not contain a method named 'OpenPrinterHandle'.

Code:

```
$code = @'
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.IO; 

   namespace OpenPrinter1
    {
   public class Program1
    {
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinter", SetLastError =true)] 
    internal static extern bool OpenPrinter(string pPrinterName, ref IntPtr   phPrinter, PRINTER_DEFAULTS pDefault);

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern int ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public class PRINTER_DEFAULTS
  {
  public string pDatatype;
  public IntPtr pDevMode;
  public int DesiredAccess;
  }

 public struct OpenPrinterAccessCodes
{
  public const int DELETE = 0x10000; // DELETE - Allowed to delete printers
  public const int READ_CONTROL = 0x20000; // READ_CONTROL - 
  public const int WRITE_DAC = 0x40000; // WRITE_DAC - 
  public const int WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000; // WRITE_OWNER - 
  public const int SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x1;
  public const int SERVER_ACCESS_ENUMERATE = 0x2;
  public const int PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x4;
  public const int PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x8;
  public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
  public const int PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | PRINTER_ACCESS_USE);
  public const int SERVER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | SERVER_ACCESS_ENUMERATE);

    public const int MAX_PORTNAME_LEN = 64;
    public const int MAX_NETWORKNAME_LEN = 49;
    public const int MAX_SNMP_COMMUNITY_STR_LEN = 33;
    public const int MAX_QUEUENAME_LEN = 33;
    public const int MAX_IPADDR_STR_LEN = 16;

    public const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    public const int ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS = 1004;
    }
    public IntPtr OpenPrinterHandle(string printerName)
    {
    var def = new PRINTER_DEFAULTS { pDatatype = null, pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero, DesiredAccess = OpenPrinterAccessCodes.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS };
    var hPrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (!OpenPrinter(printerName, ref hPrinter, def))
    {
        var lastWin32Error = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        throw lastWin32Error;
    }
    return hPrinter;
}
}
}
'@

 cls
  Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp  


  if(!([OpenPrinter1.Program1]:: OpenPrinterHandle("hp LaserJet 1320 PCL 6 (Copy 1)")))
    {
    throw (New-Object componentmodel.win32Exception )
    }
```

Comment: @Mathias: Perfect!!!!!!!

Comment: Posted as an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347632.aspx):

```
[Namespace.Class]::Method()
```

denotes invocation of a [**static** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(v=vs.71).aspx). The `OpenPrinterHandle()` method in your type definition is an [**instance** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(v=vs.71).aspx).

To change the behavior, just introduce the [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) keyword in the method signature:

```
public static IntPtr OpenPrinterHandle(string printerName)
```

and then you should be able to do:

```
[OpenPrinter1.Program1]::OpenPrinterHandle($printername)
```

Comment: Glad to help. Added a link to the "Calling Static Methods" in powershell document on TechNet