# Import [System.Printing] win32 classes to manually release print jobs

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, printing

I'm skipping the context - I have windows print jobs that go into retained status since the printer sometimes fails to notify when the job is done (not fixable). Retained jobs are considered to be actively printing, and cannot be canceled, deleted, restarted, or paused.

For example: `Remove-PrintJob` completes successfully, but the job is still around. Here's what it looks like after `Remove-PrintJob`:

```
Get-Printer $printer | Get-PrintJob -id 27 | select id,jobstatus

id JobStatus
-- ---------
27 Deleting, Printing, Retained
```

Currently my only fix is restarting the spooler service. This messes up other print queues, so I need to find another workaround.

It looks like I should be able to use the [Win32 print spooler api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setjob) function `SetJob` to manually tell the print server to finish the job:

```
SetJob()
JOB_CONTROL_SENT_TO_PRINTER    Used by port monitors to end the print job.
JOB_CONTROL_LAST_PAGE_EJECTED  Used by language monitors to end the print job.
JOB_CONTROL_RELEASE            Windows Vista and later: Release the print job.
```

...I cannot figure out how to use this though - I'm familiar with powershell, but most of the examples I've been able to find involve manually defining classes in C#. Here's what I've tried so far:

- I was able to define and run the `OpenPrinterHandle()` function using the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047843/openprinter-with-winspool-drv-not-working) which is imported from the same file: `winspool.drv`. I can see what it's doing, but I'm not sure how I would expand on it to define `SetJob()` and the other methods needed.
- I've added the `[System.Printing]` assembly, which imports many of the functions - I can get job objects and cancel them, but it doesn't contain SetJob or any other function able to set the status as far as I can tell.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing
```

I want to try running `SetJob(Job_Control_Release)` on one of my problem jobs. It doesn't have to be through powershell, but I am having the hardest time trying to import and use it.

Comment: Go to www.Pinvoke.net and look at sample code for winspool.

Comment: @jdweng beautiful, I'll try some of this out tomorrow

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295321/13566062)

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately, while pinvoke has a DllImport line I can use, I'm not sure how to write a working static method I could use from powershell to actually use it.
@SongZhu-MSFT I tried out the import in the question (since the answer excludes it) but I have the same trouble where `JOB_INFO_2` could not be found.